# Azure DevOps Deployment of asp.net app to remote iis machine

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am trying to automate a currently manual deployment process of c# solution.

The solution consists of a

- WCF project (A)
- SQl-Project (B)
- class-library reflecting the database (C)
- ASP.Net (Framework) project (D)

The current manual deployment process is as follows

- update the database using a `.public.xml` file
- update the project C via a POCO template file
- build the project A
- connect via remote desktop connection to the remote machine and copy the produced dlls into the bin folder of the service
- update the wcf service reference from D to A
- build project D
- connect to the same remote machine and also copy the produced dlls#

I would like to use a Release pipeline to automate this proces whenever there is a push to a certina branch.

I tried to use the task [PowerShellOnTargetMachines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) to run scripts on the remote machine to emulate the manual process.
But it always fails to connect, with the following error:

```
2020-07-29T12:04:38.9664113Z ##[error]Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server 109.235.140.157 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'
2020-07-29T12:05:07.6137139Z ##[error]The remote session query failed for <ip-address> with the following error message: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. 
2020-07-29T12:05:07.6713194Z ##[error]PSSession could not be created for Machine:'<ip-address>:<port>'
```

I also tried to use the [WindowsMachineFileCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task, to deploy the build arthifacts, but it also always fails with the following errors:

```
2020-07-22T13:55:04.4249345Z ##[error]Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination: '<destFolder>', ErrorMessage: 'The network path was not found'
2020-07-22T13:55:04.6782458Z ##[error]The network path was not found
```

Does anybody know which kind of prerequisites the remote machine has to meet to being able to use these two task?

Or does anyone has a better idea how this process can be automated with Azure-DevOps-Pipelines?

Comment: Do you use microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent? Is your target machine accessible over the network? You need to make sure your build agent can find your target machine.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT _"microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent"_ a self hosted agent. _"Is your target machine accessible over the network?"_ of yeah you are right forgot about that, I can only connect to the machine if I'm connected to corporate VPN.

Comment: Do you mean you have found the root cause of the issue? Is it solved?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT no it is not yet solved. I just realized (thanks to your comment) that I need to speek to your SysAdmin to make the Remote Machine available from the internet. But I would appreciate any link to some resources on the topic and troubleshooting of creating such pipeline.

Comment: You may tried configuring an agent on the target machine to see whether it can solve your issue.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT what kind of agent?

Comment: A self-hosted agent, you can configure a new one on your target machine, and deploy with this agent.